# Granting access to multiple users to sessions state on AngularJs (JHipster Project)

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

Working with the JHipster schema/project I've trying to grant access multiple users to the ‘sessions’ state (not just one) without succeed.

I've tried to follow the schema as it follows

From:

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                parent: 'site',
                url: '/home',
                data: {
                    roles: [Admin]
                },
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'scripts/app/main/main.html',
                        controller: 'MainController'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    mainTranslatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate,$translatePartialLoader) {
                        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('main');
                        return $translate.refresh();
                    }]
                }
            });
    });
```

To:

```
 data: {
        roles: [Admin,User]
        }
```

Or:

```
data: {
        roles: [{Admin},{User}]
        }
```

But is not working at all. It's something else it has to be modified?

Answer (score 0):

How did you define Admin and User?

Unless you changed it, JHipster roles in state data properties are expected to be strings and those strings should match what is defined in AuthoritiesConstants.java on server side.

```
            data: {
                roles: ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN']
            },
```